# Hide Group view in ExpandableList

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've got an expandableList using two cursors : 1 for group, another for children related to the group.
User can use a filter (alphaindexer) on this expandable list. 
I would like to completely delete the groupview when there are no children (not only the icon :)). It's like I delete the line for the empty group.

I try to set visibility to gone in bindgroupview method. I try to set the layout height for the group view....Result is the same, the space is still kept and displayed.

Is it possible and how can I do this feature?

Some code below:

```
// mMapSeqArticle is TreeMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>)
mSequenceAdapter = new SequenceCommandeAdapter(getActivity(), mMapSeqArticle);

public class SequenceCommandeAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        Object[] mGroupSeq = null;
        Map<Sequence, ArrayList<TicketArticle>> mContent;

        public SequenceCommandeAdapter(Context c,
                Map<Sequence, ArrayList<TicketArticle>> map) {
            mContent = map;
            mGroupSeq = mContent.keySet().toArray();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            Sequence s = (Sequence) mGroupSeq[groupPosition];
            return ((ArrayList<TicketArticle>) (mContent.get(s)))
                    .get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            Sequence s = (Sequence) mGroupSeq[groupPosition];
            return ((ArrayList<TicketArticle>) (mContent.get(s)))
                    .get(childPosition).mId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // retrouve la valeur de la sequence
            TicketArticle ta = (TicketArticle) getChild(groupPosition,
                    childPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.adapter_row_article_details_table, null);
            }



            convertView.setTag(groupPosition + ":" + childPosition);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            Sequence s = (Sequence) mGroupSeq[groupPosition];
            return ((ArrayList<TicketArticle>) (mContent.get(s))).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return (Sequence) mGroupSeq[groupPosition];// mContent.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mContent.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return ((Sequence) mGroupSeq[groupPosition]).key;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.adapter_header_sequence_details_table, null);
            }


            convertView.setTag(null);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the bindGroupView method in your code, but from what you've described, it sounds like you're on the right track. I've have to set the visibility of all sub views (including layouts) of the to GONE in order for the group row to completely disappear from the expandable list view. Otherwise, the empty row remains.

If you post the contents of R.layout.adapter_header_sequence_details_table, I'd have a better idea of the other things you need to make GONE.